# How to take composition of 2 bilinear transforms

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, bilinear-form

I want to take the composition of the following 2 bilinear tranforms:

1) $z\mapsto z/i$

2) $z\mapsto -2z/ ((1+i)z+2i)$

How do I do this?

Comment: As usual: name your first function $f_1$, the second $f_2$ and compute $f_1\circ f_2$ or $f_2\circ f_1$.

Comment: Can you show me how to compute that?

Comment: Of course.  Have a glimpse at the “answer,” please.

Comment: You could multiply the matrices $A = \pmatrix{1&0\\\ 0&i}$  and  $B = \pmatrix{-2&0\\\ 1+i&2i}$ in either order, $A*B$ , $ B*A$  to get composition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f_2\bigl(f_1(z)\bigr)=\frac{-2\frac zi}{(1+i)\frac zi +2i}.$$

You may consider a function as an action.  So $f_1$ is described by the action: “Divide by $i$!”  Hence $f_1\bigl(f_2(z)\bigr)$ calls you: “Divide $f_2(z)$ by $i$!”  Now do so, please.